# Get with the ajax data into a php file

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to build a login system with ajax and php. I use a log-view where I then save the data in ajax which brings into my doLogin.php (php file). My problem is that php file should never be any ajax data for when I build it into a class and a function

VIEW:

```
public function DoLoginBox() {  
    //inloggning form-tagg...
    return '<p>&nbsp;</p>
        <div id="content">
          <h1>Login Form</h1>
          <form id="form1" name="form1" action="Handler/doLogin.php"  method="post">
            <p>
              <label for="username">Username: </label>
              <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
            </p>
            <p>
              <label for="password">Password: </label>
              <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
            </p>
            <p>
              <input type="submit" id="login" name="login" />
            </p>
          </form>
            <div id="message"></div>
        </div>';
}
```

AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("#login").click(function() {
    var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
    var form_data = {
        username: $("#username").val(),
        password: $("#password").val(), 
        is_ajax: 1
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(response)
        {
            if(response == 'success')
                $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
                    $("#message").html("<p class='success'>You have logged in successfully!</p>");
                });
            else
                $("#message").html("<p class='error'>Invalid username and/or password.</p>");   
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
 require_once ("UserHandler.php");
 class DoLogingHandler{

public function Login (){
    $is_ajax = !empty($_REQUEST['is_ajax']);

    if(isset($is_ajax) && $is_ajax)
    {
        $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
        $UserHandler = new UserHandler();
        $UserHandler -> controllDB($username,$password);

        if($username == 'demo' && $password == 'demo')
        {
            echo "success";

        }
    }
}
```

}
    ` $DoLogingHandler = new DoLogingHandler();
     $DoLogingHandler->Login();
    ?>

---

if I add class and functions in stack.php I get "Error connecting to server" (I want this code into a class and function to call other functions:

```
<?php
class DologinHandler{  
public function Login(){ 
if(isset($_REQUEST['is_ajax']))
    {
        $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
        //$UserHandler = new UserHandler();
        //$UserHandler -> controllDB($username,$password);
        if($username == 'demo' && $password == 'demo')
        {
            exit('success');
        } else {
            exit('error');
        }
    }
}
```

}
  ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

First File **classes.php**

```
<?php
class loginHandler{
    public static function doLogin(){
        if(!isset($_POST['is_ajax']) || !isset($_POST['username'])  || !isset($_POST['password'])){
            return false;
        }
        if(isset($_REQUEST['is_ajax']))
        {
            $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
            $password = $_REQUEST['password'];
            //$UserHandler = new UserHandler();
            //$UserHandler -> controllDB($username,$password);
            if($username == 'demo' && $password == 'demo')
            {
                exit('success');
            } else {
                exit('error');
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Second File **index.php**

```
<?php
    require_once('classes.php');
    loginHandler::doLogin();//for static methods
    /*
        //or use this syntax for non static method
        $c = new loginHandler;
        $c->doLogin();
    */
?>
<html>
<head> <title>1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>  
</head>
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div id="content">
  <h1>Login Form</h1>
  <form id="form1" name="form1" action="index.php"  method="post" onsubmit="return loginMe()">
    <p>
      <label for="username">Username: </label>
      <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label for="password">Password: </label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" id="login" name="login"/>
    </p>
  </form>
    <div id="message"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function loginMe(){
        var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
        var form_data = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val(), 
            is_ajax: 1
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: action,
            data: form_data,
            success: function(data){
                if(typeof(data) != 'undefined' && (data == 'success' || data == 'error')){
                    if($.trim(data) == 'success'){
                        $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
                            $("#message").html("<p class='success'>You have logged in successfully!</p>");
                        });
                    } else if($.trim(data) == 'error'){
                        $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
                            $("#message").html("<p class='error'>Invalid username and/or password.</p>");
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                    $("#message").html("<p class='error'>Error to connect to server</p>");   
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MaxTorstensson: I tested the code, it doesn't any error, check your php class and make sure the php code is top of the html code.

Comment: @MaxTorstensson, if you have any problem, i can put the all code in single file and copy it here

Comment: Yes, please do so I can I share it later: =)

Comment: it's work but my problem was i will have the php-code in functions and class so i can call antoher functions. :)